# How to disable all Windows useless built-in apps and features

Tags: windows-10

I am using a VM for a game EVE Online and in this VM I only run game and not any other supporting thing like Xbox Game Bar Overlay etc.

I have deleted all WUP apps and other installed apps

I want that my system use minimum RAM and CPU and only has basic things which are required to run a desktop apps...

```
Windows 10 Pro x64
```

Comment: minimize ram usage specially even system misbehave...   only desktop can run. and Remote Desktop Connection.

I have tried windows 7  but it stucks on game...

Comment: Trying to run a game in a VM is going to need a massively powerful computer - for starters you don't have a 'real' video card in it, only a software one.

Comment: This is not problem...   I will run game in lowest quality... 

I am doing some passive stuff in game on that account running in VM which even don't require staying active on it.  (Precisely I am doing mining if you know about this game)

I want to save RAM of host by assignig less to VM...

Comment: I will run a game client on host for actively playing and inside VM for passive works...

Comment: this game require about 1.4 GB ram...     I have 8GB on host...   4GB available 

I want to allocate to game on host about 1.5 GB and to VM about 2.5 GB

Comment: If minimal memory footprint is all you want and don't really care about high performance then maybe [running EVE on Linux](https://wiki.eveuniversity.org/Installing_EVE_on_Linux) would be a better solution.

Comment: Will this use same files as windows use or download a different game client?

Comment: Consider an Educational/Enterprise edition of Windows 10. They're a bit hard to get access to, but are a common way to debloat Windows.

Comment: I have a licence for educational...